# Can you change the camera angle?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there any way to change the default camera angle in LoL? I've seen some videos where the camera angle looks different, but I can't seem to do it the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, You can zoom the camera in and out but the angles are always fixed while the game is being played. When you are seeing the different camera angle it is generally on a replay video, where the camera's movement is a bit more free.